# HTML img under another img onclick() not working

Tags: javascript, html, image, tabs, onclick

I have a set of img them work as tabs and over them img of locks.

my goal is to have the lock witch is the img on top be made hidden and the tab img become clickable.

HTML

```
<div id="Tabs">
  <img class="tablinks" id="tab_button_1" onclick="tabEvent('tab_button_1', event, 'tab1')" src="Assets/Button_Tabs_Center.png" style="width:80px;height:28px;">
  <img class="tablinks" id="tab_button_2" onclick="tabEvent('tab_button_2', event, 'tab2')" src="Assets/Button_Tabs_Center.png" style="width:80px;height:28px;">
  <img class="tablinks" id="tab_button_3" onclick="tabEvent('tab_button_3', event, 'tab3')" src="Assets/Button_Tabs_Center.png" style="width:80px;height:28px;">
</div>

<div id="Tabs_locks">
  <img id="tab_lock_1" src="Assets/lock.png" style="position:relative;width:18px;height:28px;left:30px">
  <img id="tab_lock_2" src="Assets/lock.png" style="position:relative;width:18px;height:28px;left:30px">
  <img id="tab_lock_3" src="Assets/lock.png" style="position:relative;width:18px;height:28px;left:30px">
</div>
```

Javascript

```
function tabEvent(id, evt, tabName) {
    var tabcontent, tablinks;

    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }

    document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

document.getElementById("tab_lock_1").style.visibility = "hidden"
document.getElementById("tab_lock_2").style.visibility = "hidden"
document.getElementById("tab_lock_3").style.visibility = "hidden"
```

there is some css code that moves the imgs on top of each other with the tabs being z index 1 and the locks being z index 2.

whenever I make the lock img hidden it disappears but the tab img under it is not clickable it is clickable if the lock img is not in the code.

Answer (score 0):

The tab img is not clickable because although you have hidden the lock img, it still exists on top of the tab img. It doesn't disappear. Its like keeping one layer on the other.

What you can do is, use hover property. You can change the image on hover, instead of keeping 2 images one on the other.

or you could keep the lock image clickable.

Using hover property will be a better coding practice.

Edit : Another way is using a div with the onclick event and changing the background for div on hover

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Change img on hover</title>
</head>
<style>
#imgDiv1{
width : 100px ;
height : 100px ;
display : block;
background: url("Assets/lock.png");
}
#imgDiv1:hover {
width : 100px;
height : 100px ;
display : block;
background: url("Assets/Button_Tabs_Center.png") ;
}
</style>
<body>
<div id="imgDiv1" onclick="tabEvent()"></div>
<!-- Add more divs as required -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am not sure what hover property is, do you have a link to a doc.

Comment: You could try something like this :  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-image-overlay-hover-using-html-css/

Comment: I have edited the answer and added another possible way to do what you need. This too is a easy and clean approach.

Comment: Please put the answer code IN the answer and not in some external link which may go away at any time.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss You are right. Didn't think of that before. I have added the code.

Answer (score 0):

Key here is to add the CSS that makes the lock layer "click through" with `pointer-events: none;`, here let me demonstrate.

I have my functions in a namespace to make it "contained" in my `"tabthing"` and cache some things at the start in my `tabthings` object but other than that it is pretty standard.

I also dispensed with all the ID's and in-line styles and used classes as more standard when working with visual elements.

```js
(function(tabthing, undefined) {
  var tabthings = {
    tabClassName: "tab-link",
    tablockClassName: "tab-lock",
    tabcontentClassName: "tab-content",
    activeClassList: "active-show",
    inactiveClassList: "inactive-hide",
    tabLinks: {},
    tabLocks: {},
    tabContents: {},
    linksParent: {},
    locksParent: {},
    contentParent: {}
  };

  function toggleclass(thisnode, isTrue = true) {
    thisnode.classList.toggle(tabthings.activeClassList, isTrue);
    thisnode.classList.toggle(tabthings.inactiveClassList, !isTrue);
  }

  function toggleActive(thisnode) {
    toggleclass(thisnode, true);
  }

  function toggleInActive(thisnode) {
    toggleclass(thisnode, false)
  }

  function toggleRelated(thisnode) {
    let meIndex = [].indexOf.call(tabthings.linksParent.children, thisnode);
    thisnode.classList.toggle("active", true);
    if (thisnode.classList.contains("active")) {
      toggleActive(tabthings.tabContents[meIndex]);
      toggleInActive(tabthings.tabLocks[meIndex]);
    } else {
      inActivateAll(tabthings.tabLocks);
    }
  }

  function inActivateAll(things) {
    var i = things.length;
    while (i--) {
      toggleInActive(things[i]);
    }
  }

  function activateAll(things) {
    for (let i = 0; i < things.length; i++) {
      toggleActive(things[i]);
    }
  }

  function tabClickHandler(event) {
    let meTab = this; //event.target;//same as this
    // already active, do nothing
    if (this.classList.contains('active')) {
      inActivateAll(tabthings.tabContents);
      toggleActive(tabthings.tabContents[0]);
      meTab.classList.toggle("active", false);
      return;
    }
    activateAll(tabthings.tabLocks);
    inActivateAll(tabthings.tabContents);
    for (let i = 0; i < tabthings.tabLinks.length; i++) {
      tabthings.tabLinks[i].classList.toggle("active", false);
    }

    toggleRelated(meTab);
  }

  tabthing.setup = function() {
    tabthings.linksParent = document.getElementById("tab-link-container");
    tabthings.locksParent = document.getElementById("tab-lock-container");
    tabthings.contentParent = document.getElementById("tab-content-container");
    tabthings.tabLinks = document.getElementsByClassName(tabthings.tabClassName);
    tabthings.tabLocks = document.getElementsByClassName(tabthings.tablockClassName);
    tabthings.tabContents = document.getElementsByClassName(tabthings.tabcontentClassName);
    // add event handlers
    for (let i = 0; i < tabthings.tabLinks.length; i++) {
      tabthings.tabLinks[i].addEventListener("click", tabClickHandler);
    }
    // trigger first tab click event
    const clickevent = new Event('click');
    tabthings.tabLinks[0].dispatchEvent(clickevent);
  };


}(window.tabthing = window.tabthing || {}));
// call the setup function
tabthing.setup();
```

```css
.mass-container {
  border: 1px solid lime;
  display: flex;
}

#tab-link-container,
#tab-lock-container {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
}

#tab-link-container {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid red;
  top: 1px;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 12;
}

#tab-lock-container {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: -100%;
  display: grid;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  top: 1px;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 1;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 12;
  pointer-events: none;
}

#tab-content-container {
  border: solid cyan 1px;
  display: grid;
}

.tab-content {
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 1;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 12;
}

.tab-link,
.tab-lock {
  margin-left: 1rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.tab-lock {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.tab-lock-1 {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 4;
}

.tab-lock-2 {
  grid-column-start: 5;
  grid-column-end: 8;
}

.tab-lock-3 {
  grid-column-start: 9;
  grid-column-end: 12;
}

.active-show {
  visibility: visible;
}

.inactive-hide {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.active {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="mass-container">
  <div id="tab-link-container">
    <span class="tab-link tab-link-1"><img src="Assets/Button_Tabs_Center.png" alt="first-img" /></span>
    <span class="tab-link tab-link-2"><img src="Assets/Button_Tabs_Center.png" alt="second-img" /></span>
    <span class="tab-link tab-link-3"><img src="Assets/Button_Tabs_Center.png" alt="third-img" /></span>
  </div>
  <div id="tab-lock-container">
    <span class="tab-lock tab-lock-1 "><img src="Assets/lock.png" alt="1lck" /></span>
    <span class="tab-lock tab-lock-2"><img src="Assets/lock.png" alt="2lck" /></span>
    <span class="tab-lock tab-lock-3"><img src="Assets/lock.png" alt="3lck" /></span>
  </div>

</div>
<div id="tab-content-container">
  <div class="tab-content"><h2>h2 is good</h2>First off this is content</div>
  <div class="tab-content"><h2>tab2 cool</h2>Second we have more content</div>
  <div class="tab-content"><h2>tab3 Yay</h2>Now, this is still content</div>
</div>
```